# ImportError: No module named nltk.classify

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, nltk

I'm using python 2.7, Django 1.11.14, I dockerized my app and I have a problem importing nltk.classify while executing docker-compose up

I get:

```
....
web_1  |   File "/code/personal/classifier.py", line 6, in <module>
web_1  |     from nltk.classify import ClassifierI
web_1  | ImportError: No module named nltk.classify
```

I added some lines to requirements.txt and still it dosent work
requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.11.14
psycopg2
nltk
nltk.classify
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

EDIT 1

Actually I found the problem, I changed the file **requirements.txt** and I did **docker-compose up** but this dont take on consideration the **Dockerfile** and the **requirements.txt**, so I just have to add all my libraries in the **requirements.txt** and rebuild,
But anyway, I still have a problem importing **stopwords** fron **nltk.corpus**

my requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.11.14
psycopg2
nltk
statistics
```

and running **docker-compose up** I get:

`web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", line 81, in __load
web_1  |     except LookupError: raise e
web_1  | LookupError:
web_1  | **********************************************************************
web_1  |   Resource stopwords not found.
web_1  |   Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
web_1  |
web_1  |   >>> import nltk
web_1  |   >>> nltk.download('stopwords')
web_1  |
web_1  |   Searched in:
web_1  |     - '/root/nltk_data'
web_1  |     - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
web_1  |     - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
web_1  |     - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
web_1  |     - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
web_1  |     - '/usr/local/nltk_data'
web_1  |     - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
web_1  |     - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
web_1  | **********************************************************************`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added those lines in the script where I use stopwords:

`import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')`

Answer (score 0):

`nltk.classify` is not a package but it is contained in the `ntlk` package. As the command `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` will probably fails, none of the packages will be installed. Try to delete `nltk.classify` from your `requirements.txt` and try again.

Comment: Actually it wasent there, I added it after having this error, and same result with or without it

Comment: I dont think so, pip --version gave me 

         pip 10.0.1 from ....\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip (python 2.7)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem... Perhaps you have a costum py file in your project named nltk. so python import it instead of the actual package?

Comment: No, and that's very wierd cause before dockerizing it, when I do python manage.py runserver, everything runs very well,  have a look at my docker-compose.yml

`version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python2 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db`